# Python Bytes & Lists & Encryption

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, encryption

I'm using Fernet to encrypt my data with [this implementation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet.encrypt). Let's assume that I have these three data:

```
data = [fernet.encrypt("Hello".encode()), fernet.encrypt("Stack".encode()), fernet.encrypt("Overflow".encode())]
```

After this operation, Python automatically converts `bytes` to `string`, and I'm writing them to a csv file. When I need to decrypt them like:

```
fernet.decrypt(data)
```

It gives me an error like you can only decrypt only bytes etc. I also checked that my data in the csv file is already bytes but string form.

```
b'gAAAAABiVUw5BzOkOv3VxlV5xa57Iaf0R4dzPbgsrnheAME8uYeslCZfTx9GeyRWe7l9VMM-gdDXiPZ4zsAXoXkG6T1dyXH6EztcqirrPhXX3YCt65_3xXvykVTDPdbEXs51cHvR-3HH'
```

Comment: `data` is a `list`. You’ll need to pass each element of the list into the `.decode()` method *not* the list itself.

Comment: Like ```df[column name][0].decode()```? If I understand wright it says ```str object has no attribute decode```

Comment: Because strings of type `str` do not need to be decoded (from `bytes`), it's already a string.  Perhaps do some (more) research on the `str.encode()` and `bytes.decode()` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An end-to-end usage example for encoding, writing to text, reading, and decoding.

The `Fernet` documentation can be [referenced here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/).

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# Auto-generate a secret key.
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

# Encode the string 'Hello' and encrypt.
encoded = f.encrypt('Hello'.encode())
```

This creates a bytestring (a `bytes` object) as:

```
b'gAAAAABiVVOOeO-hUG2QaKCVOyshntpbqVbxnexIVsFr7ttBGmKhHlDeM7jkTCjPPGphZxbh4D15X82pts3hKes12DjzwI8_jQ=='
```

Write, read and decrypt:

```
# Write the *decoded* encrypted string to a TXT file.
with open('/tmp/encoded.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(encoded.decode())
    
# Read the encrypted string from TXT file.
with open('/tmp/encoded.txt') as fh:
    encoded = fh.read()
    
# Encode the string, pass through fernet for decryption, 
# and decode the bytes output.
f.decrypt(encoded.encode()).decode()
```

Output:

```
'Hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

`fernet.encrypt` returns `bytes` (I assume, you're not being specific which implementation you're using, I'm guessing [this one](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet.encrypt)). `.decode()` them to a string. Then your CSV will contain "gAAA...", not "b'gAAA...'". When reading those again from the CSV, `.encode()` the string before passing it to `fernet.decrypt`.

- `fernet.encrypt` returns `bytes`
- `bytes.decode()` turns `bytes` into `str`
- CSV wants `str`
- `str.encode()` turns `str` into `bytes`
- `fernet.decrypt` wants `bytes`

Comment: I'll accept the answer after the timer ends. It worked. I missed the step of decoding..